I have a trading bot hardhat master bot that runs a smart contract in a hardhat environment with alchemy, but if I want to run a command
I have a trading bot hardhat master bot that runs a smart contract in a hardhat environment with alchemy, but if I want to run a command
npx hardhat run scripts/manipulate.js --network localhost
It gives me an error
trading_bot_hardhat-master$ npx hardhat run scripts/manipulate.js --network localhost
Beginning Swap...
Input Token: SHIB
Output Token: WETH
ProviderError: Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'
at HttpProvider.request (/home/runner/RowdyAlertStruct/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:96:21)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at HardhatEthersSigner.sendTransaction (/home/runner/RowdyAlertStruct/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers/src/signers.ts:125:18)
at send (/home/runner/RowdyAlertStruct/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:313:20)
at Proxy.swapExactTokensForTokens (/home/runner/RowdyAlertStruct/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:352:16)
at manipulatePrice (/home/runner/RowdyAlertStruct/trading_bot_hardhat-master/scripts/manipulate.js:63:16)
at main (/home/runner/RowdyAlertStruct/trading_bot_hardhat-master/scripts/manipulate.js:30:3)
I checked and verified all the errors mentioned in the error message and did not find the reason for it being that it is supposed to transfer currencies from one wallet to another wallet or that it crashes and does not transfer anything.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
